# presenting modal view controller from app delegate with storyboards

Tags: ios, storyboard, modalviewcontroller

If I regret one thing in my iOS project it is that I started to use storyboards from the beginning. Now I have all kind off difficulties to find proper references.

In this particular case I just want to display a modal view controller right after application did finish launching from AppDelegate. Quite easy but I can't get it done right now:

```
    - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{    
    AppStartViewController *appStartViewController = [[AppStartViewController alloc] init];
    UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:appStartViewController];
    [navController setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationFullScreen];

    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];

    UIViewController *vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MyInitialViewController"];
    [vc presentModalViewController:navController animated:NO];

    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    return YES;
}
```

Any ideas what went wrong or where's my mistake in thinking?

Answer (score 3):

I think vc is not on your view yet. You first need to present the vc view controller.

`self.window.rootViewController = vc;`

`[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];`

A modal view controller can only be presented by another view controller which is already on the view.

Comment: I think it is on view - vc is instantiated with the view controller from the storyboard with the identifier "MyInitialViewController". At least thats what I guess. Changing the code like you suggested only causes the initial view controller to be displayed as model view controller